# Как установить библиотеку boost?

Tags: boost, c++, библиотеки, visual-studio-2010

Доброго времени суток. Нужна помощь!

Хочу установить библиотеку boost. Во всех туториалах люди заходят в консольку Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010). Но проблема в том, что я не могу ее найти! Искать в винде пробовал - не нашел.

У меня экспресс-версия! Дело в этом?

Answer (score 14):

Библиотека boost - это набор частично компилируемых исходных кодов. В некоторых случаях ничего не нужно собирать, достаточно скачать с официального сайта дистрибутив, разместить в удобном месте и в настройках проекта указать пути.

У меня в специальной папке, где я храню библиотеки многоразового использования, лежит подпапка `boost_1_56_0`. Рядом с нею еще ряд других более старых версий этой библиотеки.

В переменные среды (в windows это там же, где и PATH) я заношу переменную `BOOST_ROOT`, которая указывает на последнюю сборку. Т.е. как появится новая, я создам папку `boost_1_XX_Y` и переназначу эту переменную.

В настройках любых проектов мне достаточно указать $(BOOST_ROOT)\include - для доступа к headers, и `$(BOOST_ROOT)\stage\lib32` / `$(BOOST_ROOT)\stage\lib64` для доступа к конкретным библиотекам, нужной мне разрядности.

Поскольку boost автоматически выдает имена собираемым библиотекам, с учетом компиляторов, которыми они собираются, даже если у Вас разные компиляторы, бинарники удобно сбрасывать в одну папку, как указано выше.

- С Intel Compiler у Вас получатся `libboost_name-iw-type-version.lib`.
- С Visual Studio у Вас получатся `libboost_name-vcXX-type-version.lib`, где XX - версия компилятора visual studio (не студии, а именно компилятора).
- С MinGW с gcc у Вас получится `libboost_name-gcc-type-version.lib`, если мне не изменяет память.

При этом для сборки библиотек, которые необходимо собирать, необходимо выполнить одни и те же действия в консоли:

- Для Intel Compiler это будет в соответствующем Command Prompt.
- Для Visual Studio это будет в соответствующем Command Prompt.
- Для MinGW это будет в обычной консоли, если, конечно, путь к bin в MinGW у Вас добавлен в переменную среды PATH.

Действия надо выполнить одни и те же. Сначала `bootstrap.bat`, а потом `b2 --help`.

В хелпе b2 Вы увидите все варианты настройки сборки, чтобы собрать наиболее удобным Вам образом.

Строчка будет выглядеть так:

b2 *параметр1* *параметр2* *параметр3* ...

- toolset - его стоит указать, чтобы сборка производилась конкретным компилятором (gcc, intel, visual studio), причем можно указать и версию компилятора.
- variant, вид сборки, debug или release. Для разработки Вам понадобятся оба варианта.
- link - Вы выбираете, будет Ваш бинарный код обращаться в dll или содержать "в себе" все используемые алгоритмы.
- threading - честно говоря, плохо понимаю смысл этой директивы и всегда указываю multi. Редко мы пишем однопоточные приложения.
- runtime-link - то же, что и link, только для рантайма.
- address-model - параметр не указан в хелпе, но помогает выбрать архитектуру собираемых библиотек.
- stage/install, отличаются лишь тем, что install позволит "выгрузить" только нужное в отдельную папку, stage собирает всё туда, где оно есть. Если Вы не увлекаетесь изменениями исходников boost, stage Вам вполне подойдет.

В итоге получается что-то вроде вот такого:

```
b2 toolset=vc120 variant=debug link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared address-model=32 stage
```

Для дебага в x32 и такого:

```
b2 toolset=vc120 variant=release link=static threading=multi runtime-link=shared address-model=32 stage
```

Для релиза в x32.

Ждете около 40 минут, радуетесь результату. В случае проблем - гуглите, скорее всего уже тысячи людей сталкивались с Вашей проблемой, и ее решение - невнимательность или какие-то специфические настройки чего-нибудь. Например, при сборке boost python вылезает много warning-ов на MinGW из-за конфликта хедеров, подобные вещи можно разрулить в частном порядке.

Потратив 2 часа на то, чтобы один раз в этом разобраться, Вы никогда не будете зависеть ни от каких сторонних сборок, будете понимать, где у Вас что лежит, кто туда положил и т.п. В общем, это полезно.

ЗЫ: Command Prompt находится в Visual Studio Tools. Или посмотрите в VStudio_PATH\CommonXX\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat

Comment: Ого, вот это подробный tutorial.

Comment: @Arkady : Я хоть и заплюсовал, но хочется отдельно поблагодарить за такое пояснение! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, самый простой способ - это установить заранее собранный пакет под ваш компилятор. Брать [тут](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.56.0/).

Answer (score -2):

Есть программка, называется BlueGo, по адресу: [ссылка](http://vertexwahn.de/bluego.html). Это сборник различных библиотек в том числе и boost, но плюс ее в том, что там есть абсолютно все версии, начиная со старых и заканчивая новыми. Выбираешь версию, выбираешь чем компилировать, выбираешь состав сборки и ждешь окончания.