# Подключение boost к Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

Гуглил, устанавливают через command prompt, но я его не нашел. Подскажите другие способы по подключению boost к visual studio 2017

Comment: В меню студии: Tools->Visual Studio Command Prompt

Answer (score 0):

Инструкция как открыть Visual Studio Command Prompt : [How-to-open VSP](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/706617/How-to-open-Visual-studio-command-Prompt-using-Win)

Связанные вопрос с подробным ответом : [Как установить библиотеку boost?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/368975/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-boost)